# Why does maximized Chrome report its display-mode as 'fullscreen'?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, media-queries, progressive-web-apps

In my web app, I need to know whether I can open a new window or not (e.g. with `target='_blank'`). I can safely open a new window when running in a browser, but not when running as a PWA (in `standalone` mode).

To test whether I can open a new window, I'm using [the `display-mode` media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode), like this:

```js
document.body.innerText = 'Your display-mode is ' +JSON.stringify(
  ['fullscreen', 'standalone', 'minimal-ui', 'browser'].filter(
    mode => window.matchMedia(`(display-mode: ${mode})`).matches))
```

This works in Firefox and Safari, which both report the mode `browser`. But Chrome, when its window is maximized, reports the mode `fullscreen`! This doesn't make sense, because the meaning of `fullscreen` is "All of the available display area is used and no user agent chrome is shown."

Questions:

1. Is this a bug in Chrome? Should it not always report the mode `browser`?
2. Is there a less hacky way I can test for the ability to open a new window?

Comment: Update: maximized Chrome on Windows reports its mode as `browser`, so it seems like this is specific to macOS ...

Comment: Okay, I reported it at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1273386